# Skip if jar file exist and continue

Tags: java

I have code that inserts an Excel spreadsheet into files in one folder. I need a feature that allows me to omit certain .jar files (because it's unnecessary - depend files). However, I want the table insertion to continue. I've come to the conclusion that if a file exists, it will stop.

```
     if (AddTable) {
        File table_folder = new File("tablesjar/");
        File[] sheets = table_folder.listFiles();
        File ignore = new File("Depend.jar");

        for (File sheets_file : sheets) {
          if (!ignore.exists()) {
            if (sheets_file.isDirectory())
                continue;

            if (!sheets_file.equals(ignore))
                continue;
          }     
        }
    }
```

so how to solve it? I have 400 .jar files in the folder and pasting manually would be unnecessary.

Comment: What happens when you try this? You current code doesn't do anything, so how can you tell if it stops or continues? All three branches lead to the same consequence.

Answer (score 0):

May be there is a better way to do hole action, based on https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-filter-the-files-by-file-extensions-and-show-the-file-names-in-java :

```
  if (AddTable) {
    File table_folder = new File("tablesjar");
    File[] sheets = table_folder.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File item) {
            if (item.getName().endsWith(".jar") ||item.isDirectory()) {
                //Ignore it
                return false;
            } else {
                //Don't ignore it
                return true;
            }
        }
    });
    //After that you can work on a clean file array
    for (File singleSheet : sheets) {
      //Whatever you want do to with it
    }
   }
```